# Click and drag scrolling in Edge causes split second freezes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, microsoft-edge

Click and drag scrolling in edge seems to cause a small jittery behaviour as opposed to being smooth like in chrome,ff and even in IE11, all clickdrag examples 4-5 that I found on google exhibited same behaviour in edge.

For example: https://codepen.io/toddwebdev/pen/yExKoj

some code because.

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.items');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;
```

Perhaps someone has encountered the issue and found a solution?

Comment: Your issue may be related to this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/jerky-scrolling-in-microsoft-edge-browser/ea08f2c8-86f4-444c-9a10-fd1e74e2e9b5

Comment: Have you considered the idea of building your own custom horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @acarlstein Did it jitter on your Edge as well? If I were to build my own, I would still resort to looking at examples that already exist(as I tested several on edge but no luck), so I wouldnt really know what to make differently, that the Edge bug wouldnt happen.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question itself.

Comment: @Helpme, I would advice to check how to create your own scrollbar. 
Pretty much, you will disable the default horizontal bar and implement your own. I did a quick search online and found several examples. Try that out and lets see if solves your problem. Insisting on using the default horizontal scrollbar given to you by Edge may end into "beating a dead horse"

Comment: @TylerH Isnt the codepen example enough?, does it work smooth for you on all browsers including Edge? 
acarlstein I'm confused? are you talking about styling a scrollbar? I'm talking about the click and drag scrolling, that is not smooth on edge.

Comment: @Helpme No, the rules of the site require that the question itself contain the MCVE. The reason is that when codepen goes down or when that links contents change, the issue is no longer reproducible and thus the question loses its value.

Comment: I made a test on 2 MS Edge versions but I am not able to produce the issue with you above code. Here is a test result with MS Edge 42.17134.1.0 https://i.postimg.cc/zDMYT1R9/69.gif This is the test result with MS Edge 44.17763.1.0 https://i.postimg.cc/jSTxJrpR/70.gif Let me know, Which exact version you are using on your end. If you are using any older version than I suggest you to update with latest MS Edge and again try to check the issue with it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks for the tests, but you used the scrollbar which I dont have any issue with it. If you can test again, try click and drag on the elements to scroll.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the requirement, I will again make a test and will inform you the testing result.

Comment: I again made a test with both Edge versions. Testing result with 42.17134.1.0 https://i.postimg.cc/Y0L2Lf8L/72.gif Testing result with 44.17763.1.0 https://i.postimg.cc/yNryVsG6/73.gif Still the scrolling is smooth on my side with these two versions. Can you please inform us, Which version of Edge you are using? It can help us to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks, Using Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 and to be clear you also used another browser, chrome for example to get a sense of the smoothness? It kinda either freezes splitsecond or jumps when clicking and dragging. Well if you don't experience any issues it's sort of good news.

Comment: Yes, I also tested it many times in Chrome and Edge and I did not get any difference in scrolling. I suggest you to try to make a test with any other machine to check whether you are able to reproduce the issue with it or not.